# Crystal Report Unable to load report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a working report developed in Crystal report 8. I need to add a new sub-report so whenever I add it and deploy it to an IIS server that is connection to the database I used in development, it works well. When I try to deploy it on production, it gave me unable to load report with the below stack trace

```
[COMException (0x8000020d): Unable to load report.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +0
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +159
```

Comment: I have had ComExceptions before when the schema of the report and database does not match or parameter is missing.  Compare fields on you Prod db and report. If it works without sub report in Prod then possibly the subreport has a missing field

Answer (score 0):

This might not be related to Crystal at all. The report will be loaded with the permissions of the user who is used to run IIS. Check if this user has permissions to read files in reports folder. Also, if you are using integrated security you need to add the user to the database.